# Marketplace purchase sharing does not work by the end of December 2021

Tags: magento2, marketplace

Our customers used to give us shared access to their accounts on Magento.com, as described here: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/magento/magento-marketplace.html.

This way, we did not have to use the access keys of our customers to install purchased extensions. We could stick to our own access keys and when customer revokes shared access, the extensions are gone for us.

By the end of December we lost access to the payed commerce edition of one of our customers. The customer did not revoke our access.

At the same time, the purchased extensions of one of our OS customers, who gave us shared access, are also no longer visible to us.

Is this sharing functionality still active?

If not, what is the way to go when developing for various customers with more than 1 developer?